# Convert a list into a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I need to convert my `list` into a 3 column `pandas` `DataFrame` (`time`, `id` and `ret_exc_lead1m`).

However it looks like this:

```
 [time        id            
 2010-01     comp_001661_01W   -0.041371
             comp_002410_04W   -0.053836
             comp_004367_02W    0.024752
             comp_004439_08W    0.013136
             comp_011749_09W   -0.013695
             comp_011925_01W    0.043677
 2010-02     comp_001661_01W   -0.041371
             comp_012384_14W   -0.014593
             comp_013498_01W    0.060748
             comp_015321_02W   -0.053604
             comp_015334_02W   -0.155894
 2010-03     comp_001661_01W   -0.041371
             comp_015532_10W    0.003835
             comp_015575_01W   -0.045820
             comp_015576_01W    0.032070
             comp_015598_03W    0.028164
             comp_015617_02W   -0.053060
             comp_015634_05W    0.102842
             comp_018636_04W   -0.029271
 2010-04     comp_001661_01W   -0.041371
             comp_019349_01W   -0.048753
             comp_019565_13W   -0.007516
             comp_025648_05W   -0.015128
             comp_029097_01W    0.085202
             comp_029804_04W   -0.011097
 2010-05     comp_001661_01W   -0.041371
             comp_030807_03W   -0.139678
             comp_031137_03W   -0.042764
             comp_031142_05W    0.055970
             comp_062806_93W   -0.104863
             comp_063914_02W    0.044195
             comp_063987_91W   -0.010617
 2010-06     comp_001661_01W   -0.041371
             comp_064835_03W    0.020164
             comp_064835_90W    0.047719
             comp_065248_07W   -0.045530
  Name: ret_exc_lead1m, dtype: float32]
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to do it.

Comment: What is the format of your `list`? How is it structured before attempting to convert?

Comment: This is not a python conforming list format in any way. [mre] and touch up on [ask] please.

Comment: @PatrickArtner: it is indeed a list, but containing a pandas Series as single element...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the dimension of your input list. Basically, if your list has one dimension, then the conversion will look like:

```
import pandas as pd 
your_list= ['a', 'few', 'important', 'words']
df = pd.DataFrame(lst) 
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   0
0  a
1  few
2  important
3  words
```

If the list is well structured and has 2 or more dimensional, you can directly point columns you want:

```
import pandas as pd 
lst = [['dog', 'black', 1], ['cat', 'grey', 15], ['monkey', 'brown', 2]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns =['Animal', 'Color', 'Quantity'], dtype = float) 
print(df)
```

Result:

```
   Animal  Color  Quantity
0     dog  black       1.0
1     cat   grey      15.0
2  monkey  brown       2.0
```

In the case, if you have a few 1d lists it's possible to use `zip()` function:

```
import pandas as pd 
l_1 = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']
l_2 = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(l_1, l_2)), columns =['First Column', 'Second Column']) 
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  First Column  Second Column
0        first              1
1       second              2
2        third              3
3       fourth              4
```

Answer (score 1):

I shall assume that your list contains in fact a single element which is a Pandas Series. You just have to:

- extract the unique element from your list
- reset the index of the Series

Code is simply (assuming your list is `l`):

```
l[0].reset_index()
```

It should give:

```
       time               id  ret_exc_lead1m
0   2010-01  comp_001661_01W       -0.041371
1   2010-01  comp_002410_04W       -0.053836
2   2010-01  comp_004367_02W        0.024752
3   2010-01  comp_004439_08W        0.013136
4   2010-01  comp_011749_09W       -0.013695
5   2010-01  comp_011925_01W        0.043677
6   2010-02  comp_001661_01W       -0.041371
7   2010-02  comp_012384_14W       -0.014593
8   2010-02  comp_013498_01W        0.060748
9   2010-02  comp_015321_02W       -0.053604
10  2010-02  comp_015334_02W       -0.155894
11  2010-03  comp_001661_01W       -0.041371
12  2010-03  comp_015532_10W        0.003835
13  2010-03  comp_015575_01W       -0.045820
14  2010-03  comp_015576_01W        0.032070
15  2010-03  comp_015598_03W        0.028164
16  2010-03  comp_015617_02W       -0.053060
17  2010-03  comp_015634_05W        0.102842
18  2010-03  comp_018636_04W       -0.029271
19  2010-04  comp_001661_01W       -0.041371
20  2010-04  comp_019349_01W       -0.048753
21  2010-04  comp_019565_13W       -0.007516
22  2010-04  comp_025648_05W       -0.015128
23  2010-04  comp_029097_01W        0.085202
24  2010-04  comp_029804_04W       -0.011097
25  2010-05  comp_001661_01W       -0.041371
26  2010-05  comp_030807_03W       -0.139678
27  2010-05  comp_031137_03W       -0.042764
28  2010-05  comp_031142_05W        0.055970
29  2010-05  comp_062806_93W       -0.104863
30  2010-05  comp_063914_02W        0.044195
31  2010-05  comp_063987_91W       -0.010617
32  2010-06  comp_001661_01W       -0.041371
33  2010-06  comp_064835_03W        0.020164
34  2010-06  comp_064835_90W        0.047719
35  2010-06  comp_065248_07W       -0.045530
```